# Wordpress pagination stops working after page 10

Tags: wordpress, url

For some reason after getting to page 10 in my blog(ex: `/page/10`) -- the page goes to a 404.

When go to `example.com/page/11` it redirects me here:

`https://example.wpengine.com/blog/pagehttps:/example.wpengine.com/`

Cannot figure out what is going on here.

Comment: Here, share your code.

Comment: @PriyankaModi I saw your shared solution somewhere else and tried that. However, since my permalinks are set to `/blog`, my pagination links just brought me to the homepage. So that solution did not work, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on function.php file:

```html
/**
 * Fix pagination on archive pages
 * After adding a rewrite rule, go to Settings > Permalinks and click Save to flush the rules cache
 */
function my_pagination_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('blog/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=blog&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_pagination_rewrite');
```

Replace blog with your category name in the code above.

After adding this code, You can go to **Settings > Permalinks**
After, click **Save to flush the rules cache**, or else the rule will not be applied.

Get the more details about the solution, you can follow the **article** - [Fixing a WordPress pagination 404 error](http://meigwilym.com/fixing-the-wordpress-pagination-404-error/)

Comment: Yes I saw this solution somewhere else and it did not work. I believe since my permalinks are set to `/blog` -- so this just directed me back to the homepage when I tried to click any of the pagination links

Comment: which one wordpress version used in your theme integration?